# Android: activate sms reciever for limited time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm wondering is it possible to activate BroadcastRecievers onRecieve method for recieving SMS to be active only for a limited time after pressing a button?

I dont want it to be active all the time, and to conflict with my messenging app.

I a made class "public class SmsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver" and defined reciever in manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name="SmsReciever" >
        <intent-filter  >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to activate BroadcastReceiver temporarily, you should not define receiver in the manifest. You should [register receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) in the code:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"); // I don't know where in the Android SDK this string defined

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new SmsReciever();
registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

and [unregister receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29) when it is not needed more:

```
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

Comment: I doesnt work, im doing somethind wrong... Is "SmsReciever()" class i made that extends Broadcast reciever? I copied your code, and didnt recieve message, but when i came to unregisterReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
than app crashed :(

Comment: Sorry, I write `unregisterReceiver()` wrong, updated. Yes, `SmsReciever` is your class. Are there any errors in the LogCat?